# Ok to pause MacPort installation, hibernate, and continue later?

Tags: macos, hibernate, macports

I've got a MacBook and I started installing a large package (gcc 4.4) using MacPorts about an hour ago. I didn't realize it would take so long and I have to leave in a few minutes and bring my laptop with me. Is it safe to pause the MacPorts process, close my computer, open it again later, and unpause the MacPorts process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I ended up pausing, hibernating, and then continuing later and things seem to work fine!

Answer (score 1):

If there's a specific "Pause" function, then you should be fine.  If you really want to play it safe though, then abort the current process and start it again later.

Comment: By "pause", I basically mean hitting Ctrl-Z on the command line.

Comment: Well, if you're using something like "make && make install" then you should be okay to just break out of that process, and start it again later ("make" is usually smart enough to continue where it left off).